# IE jquery click only works on text in li, not entire box

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

I have a series of buttons created as li that I want the user to be able to click:

```
<ul class="item_list">
<li class="item_button" id="128" style="color: #4bb2c5" data-seq= "0">1</li>
<li class="item_button" id="129" style="color: #EAA228" data-seq= "1">2</li>
<li class="item_button" id="130" style="color: #c5b47f" data-seq= "2">3</li>
<li class="item_button" id="131" style="color: #579575" data-seq= "3">4</li>
<li class="item_button" id="132" style="color: #839557" data-seq= "4">5</li>
<li class="item_button" id="133" style="color: #958c12" data-seq= "5">6</li>
<li class="item_button" id="134" style="color: #953579" data-seq= "6">7</li>
<li class="item_button" id="135" style="color: #4b5de4" data-seq= "7">8</li>
</ul>
```

Here is the relevant css:

```
.item_button{
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ededed), color-stop(1, #dfdfdf) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100% );
    background-color:#ededed;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
        float:left;
    font-size:10pt;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:6px 24px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
        width:120px;
        margin-top:12px;
}

.item_button:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #dfdfdf), color-stop(1, #ededed) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #dfdfdf 5%, #ededed 100% );

    background-color:#dfdfdf;
}
.item_button:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

...and here is my jQuery handler:

```
$('.item_list li').click(function(){
    $('.item_list li').attr('class', 'item_button');
    $(this).attr('class','item_button_selected')
  });
```

This all works fine in Chrome and Safari.  The user can click anywhere in the li and it "clicks."  In IE, the hover behavior and the click are only caught if the user clicks directly on the text itself inside of the li, i.e. "1", "2", etc.  What am I missing?

Comment: Try: `$(this).toggleClass('item_button_selected item_button')` inside the click event and get rid of everything else, you shouldn't be using `attr('class')` because it overrides the classes that were previously set. Then initialize the first item.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kZu8h/ Works for me in IE(9).

Comment: I have the same problem, any news on this?

Comment: It's for sure some of the css because if I remove all classes from the divs it works again

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you shouldn't repeat yourself so try and update your jQuery to use $(this) in a single variable:

```
$('.item_list li').click(function() {

    var $this = $(this);

    $this.attr('class', 'item_button');
    $this.attr('class', 'item_button_selected');
});
```

Secondly, I agree with elclanrs, you should try and use toggleClass().

Regarding your IE problem, it works for me in IE9 and IE10. Which version does it not work for you? Are you using IE's compatibility mode?