# ie link button - can only click text, not space around button

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to create a vertical grouping of buttons using CSS.  Previously, [I tried doing this using an unordered list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925723/ie-jquery-click-only-works-on-text-in-li-not-entire-box).

I have since removed the unordered list and just left the buttons as  elements.  Everything works fine in Chrome and FF, but not IE8.  The only time the "hover" state is activated is when you actually hover over the text of the link, not the entire button.  I want the entire box to be clickable.

Here is the relevant code from my HTML:

```
<div id="itemarea">
      <a href="#" class="item_button" id="139" style="color: #4bb2c5" data-seq= "0">Skydiving</a>
<a href="#" class="item_button" id="140" style="color: #EAA228" data-seq= "1">Knitting</a>
<a href="#" class="item_button" id="141" style="color: #c5b47f" data-seq= "2">Checkers</a>
<a href="#" class="item_button" id="142" style="color: #579575" data-seq= "3">Surfing</a>
  <button class="save_button" name="button" type="submit">Save</button>

</div>
```

and here is the CSS:

```
#itemarea{
    padding-bottom:20px;
    margin-top:54px;
    height:470px;
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    padding-left:15px;
    background-color:#CFCFCF;
    border:2px solid gray;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -o-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow( Strength=5, Direction=135, Color='#999999' );
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow( Strength=5, Direction=135, Color='#999999' );
}


.item_button {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ededed), color-stop(1, #dfdfdf) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#dfdfdf');
    background-color:#ededed;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#777777;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:6px 24px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
        width:120px;
}.item_button:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #dfdfdf), color-stop(1, #ededed) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #dfdfdf 5%, #ededed 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#dfdfdf', endColorstr='#ededed');
    background-color:#dfdfdf;
}.item_button:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure ie8 isn't in compatibility mode, try clicking the broken page icon in the url bar